# Log super user login in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql-workbench, database-administration

How do I audit(log) super user log in MySQL?

I have used trigger as per 
http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-logon-and-logoff-trigger-for-auditing#comment-917 this link its only working for login with other than super users in init_connect variable.But i need to log super user login time with ip?Anyone tried it kindly help me to find and any other reasons super user will not log in init_connect variable?

Answer (score 0):

you can install MySQL plugin [audit_login](https://github.com/outbrain/audit_login) that will reporting what you want like this

```
{"ts":"2013-09-11 09:11:47","type":"successful_login","myhost":"gromit03","thread":"74153868","user":"web_user","priv_user":"web_user","host":"web-87.localdomain","ip":"10.0.0.87"}
{"ts":"2013-09-11 09:11:55","type":"failed_login","myhost":"gromit03","thread":"74153869","user":"backup_user","priv_user":"","host":"web-32","ip":"10.0.0.32"}
```